# Check if character is number

Tags: r, regex

I want to check if a character can be safely converted to a numeric by using a regex.

However, I don't see my error. Example:

```
stringr::str_detect("4.", pattern = "-{0,1}[0-9]+(.[0-9]+){0,1}")
```

This produces a `TRUE`. My intention was to specifiy that whenever a `.` follows the first sequence of numbers, there must be at **least one other number**, therefore `(.[0-9]+){0,1}`.

What's wrong here?

Comment: The regex for at least one occurrence should be `{1,}`. `{0,1}` means zero or one occurrence.

Comment: And you probably want to replace `.` in regex with  `\\.`

Comment: Maybe use `stringr::str_detect("4.", pattern = "^-{0,1}[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){0,1}$")`

Comment: It might be cheaper to simply convert and check if the result is not `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- `(.[0-9]+){0,1}` is an *optional* pattern because `{0,1}` (=`?`) makes the `.[0-9]+` pattern sequence match one or zero times. So, yes, one or more digits (`[0-9]+`) must follow any char other than line break chars (matched with an unescaped `.`), but this pattern is optional, and thus you cannot require anything with it.
- `.` is unescaped, so it matches any char other than line break chars. Escape it to match a literal dot
- Your regex is not anchored, and can match *partial* substrings in a longer string. Use `^` and `$` to make the pattern match the whole string.

So, consider using

```r
stringr::str_detect("4.", pattern = "^-?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?$")
```

where

- `^` - start of string
- `-?` - an optional `-` char
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970) matching an optional sequence of a `.` and then one or more digits
- `$`  - end of string.